# How To Redirect with modified URL using .htacess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, permalinks

I want to move my website to a new domain. But, facing a problem with Permalink structure. Example,

```
Old Structure: oldsite.com/salman-khan-biography/
New Structure: newsite.com/salman-khan-movies/
```

Actually, just single word will be changed from the end of permalinks.
I tried below codes, but it's showing 404 not found on the new domain.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^oldsite.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.oldsite.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://newsite.com/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
```

Comment: Are all url's have 'biography' word in end or all words in end are suppose to be replaced with 'movie' regardless?

Comment: all "POSTS" URLs end with Biography. I want to redirect with "movie"

Comment: I already changed permalink to new domain with movie. But, old domain redirect with "biography". That's the main problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with below in your old website htaccess.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)\-biography/?$
RewriteRule ^ http://newsite.com/%1-movies/ [R=301]
```