# Redirect old to new site with Modified permalink Structure

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I want to move a Website to new with modified permalink structure. 
Example:

https://example.com/tom-cruise/ ===> https://newdomain.com/tom-cruise-biography/

I mean, I want to add (biography) word end of every single post.

I tried below codes, but not working.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/?$
RewriteRule ^ https://newdomain.com/%1-biography/ [R=301]
```

Comment: Is this is similar to what you have asked earlier on this post link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50724548/how-to-redirect-with-modified-url-using-htacess

Comment: Quite similar. The previous post, I was asking to replace a word. but, this post, I want to add a word.